# How to find more than one space and replace it with one space?

Tags: sed, files, string, search, whitespace

I want to find repeated spaces (more than one) and replace them with one space. 
I tried:

```
sed -e 's/ []+/ /g' myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```

This resulted in an empty file. Why? and how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command errors out: `sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated 's' command` so there is possibly an empty file because there is no standard output generated.

Try `sed -e 's/  \+/ /g' myfile.txt > myfile2.txt`

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939323/sed-command-to-replace-multiple-spaces-into-single-spaces

Answer (score 3):

In standard `sed`, to search for one or more SPC characters, the syntax is:

```
sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'
```

Or

```
sed 's/  */ /g'
```

(that's two spaces before the star). Or to make it more legible:

```
sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g'
```

Once `-E` (for extended regular expressions) is added to the standard (which should happen in the next major POSIX release, many implementations already support it), you could also do:

```
sed -E 's/ +/ /g'
```

Some `sed` implementations also understand `\+` with basic regex (without `-E`) as an alias for `\{1,\}`.

But here, you could just use `tr` instead:

```
tr -s ' ' < file.in > file.out
```

To **s**queeze the spaces.